# Thread Safety of StringBuilder in Parallel.For

Tags: c#, parallel.for

I have created a struct, say `AStruct`, and override its `ToString()` method.  Then I have written a parallel for to return some `AStruct` and put them in a list so I can use a `StreamWriter` to output them, like

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"ABC.txt");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<AStruct> AList = new List<AStruct>();

Parallel.For(0,10,i =>                          // generate 10 AStruct(s)
{
   AList.Add(DoSomethingThatReturnsAStruct);
});

for(int i =0; i< AList.Count();i++)             //put in a StringBuilder
{
   sb.AppendLine(AList[i].ToString());
}
sw.Write(sb.ToString());
sw.Close();
```

The problem is the output file only print 7/8 lines of AList, while AList actually got all the 10 elements.  I wonder does this relate to thread-safety of StringBuilder.  Could someone explain why not all lines are output?

Comment: It's not Stringbuilder that's the issue here, it's `List<T>` that's being manipulated in parallel.

Comment: @IanMercer no its not, read his question especially the last paragraph again. _while AList actually got all the 10 elements._

Comment: @kchpchan 1,10 in the Parallel.For generates 9 elements, not 10, either do 0,10 or 1,11

Comment: @CSharpie - probably while stepping through debugging.  List<T> is not thread safe for `Add`. Fix that first.

Comment: Is that code surrounded by a try catch? Either catching a generic exception or an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code above the instance of `StringBuilder` is never accessed/modified by anything other than the `main` thread (or whatever thread is creating the `sw`) so thread-safety of `StringBuilder` is not relevant **however** you have a much bigger bug one that you should always remember when dealing with more than one thread.

> Never ever modify a shared resource by multiple threads unless that
>   resource is thread-safe

You are updating the `AList` from different threads so either use a `lock` to synchronize access or a thread-safe collection e.g. `ConcurrentQueue` (order guaranteed) or `ConcurrentBag` (order not guaranteed)

You are also adding **9** entries to the `AList` instead of **10**.

Finally here's your modified code which yields the expected result.

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(@"ABC.txt");
try
{        
    var AList = new List<AStruct>();

    var locker = new object();
    Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>                          // generate 10 AStruct(s)
    {
        lock (locker) { AList.Add(new AStruct()); }
    });

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < AList.Count; i++)             //put in a StringBuilder
    {
        sb.AppendLine(AList[i].ToString());
    }
    sw.Write(sb.ToString());
} finally
{
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: In here using `lock` would make the `Parallel.For` meaningless.  Concurrent Collections actually works for me.  Thanks!